# Update table data in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0, database-update

I have created, table (email_format) and getting form data and store to this table using model, This is my table values

```
  id      format

  Raj       text
  kumar     html
```

If customer change format for example **Kumar change html to text format** in form then, check **kumar before format and update html to text.** 
 My Output is:

```
   id      format

  Raj       text
  kumar     text
```

Comment: You can load your id in model and update format data

Comment: @ND17 , can you please  explain bit more Thanks for support

Comment: when u get form data in that what data u get and in your database id is primarykey?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to update data into your table just follow the code given below :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$this->_resources = $objectManager
        ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();

        $userTokenTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('msintegration_usertoken'); //your table name
        //$logger->info("inside usertoken update ");

        $where = $connection->quoteInto('refresh_token = ?', $refreshToken);
        $query = $connection->update($userTokenTable,
                ['access_token'=> $response['access_token']],$where );
```